# libinput - how to check if I have acceleration enabled on touchpad?

Tags: 19.04, libinput

There are only options for mouse acceleration, I don't see any for touchpad. It feels as if touchpad acceleration is off or very low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the Mouse/Touchpad acceleration on the Settings Menu:

[image]

You can find more customizations on **Gnome-Tweaks**

Install Gnome Tweaks using the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Open Terminal and run the command `gnome-tweaks` to launch the Gnome Tweaks option
[image]