# Touchpad sensitivity

Tags: touchpad

I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on a ODYS Mybook. The touchpad is working very badly. If I use the tip of my finger to control the movement of the pointer the reaction is slow and laggy. If a put larger part of my finger onto the the touchpad the control is much better. Which settings in synclient could improve the behaviour of the touchpad?

Comment: Kindly refer this link: https://askubuntu.com/a/1162911/978216

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. Definitely it is not a problem of acceleration setting. It seems to me that the fingertip is barely accepted as an input. Like I said when increasing the amount of surface covered by my finger the behaviour is much better. Double finger scroll works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe a hardware issue. Did you check the Touchpad with other OS?

Comment: It came with windows installed. It was not perfect but way better.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the Mouse/Touchpad acceleration on the Settings Menu:

[image]